# Update row by clicking a Edit button in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I have a table where all the data are showing  and in every row there is an edit button . Now what I want is after I click on the edit button a pop up/model box/lightbox whatever you say will appear without the page refresh and then all fields will appear on that box . I know how to do update in controller and model .I just don't know how I attach a following row id to delete button and then send to the controller through ajax and then populate them in the lightbox this is what I am doing.

Here is my view:

```
   <?php foreach($records as $row){?>
<tr>
<td>
    <td><?php echo $row->cat_name; ?></td>
    <td><?php $row->cat_id;?> <a toggle="modal"  href="#myModal"id="edit">Edit</a>

       <a  data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal">Delete</a>

       <div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
```

Just tell me how can  send the cat_id through ajax to controller  because in ajax we grab the value through 'id' but here how can I give id to this line.

```
       <?php $row->cat_id;?>
```

Which is behind the edit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script languae="javascript" type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $(".edit").click(function(){
        row_id = $(this).attr("row_id");
        alert(row_id)
    })

    $(".delete").click(function(){
        row_id = $(this).attr("row_id");
        alert(row_id)
    })
})


</script>
```

Please add this javascript in your file and do some changes in your HTML remove id attribute in anchor tag. add class property

```
<a toggle="modal"  href="#myModal" class="edit" row_id="<?php $row->cat_id;?>">Edit</a>

       <a  data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="delete" row_id="<?php $row->cat_id;?>">Delete</a>
```

Comment: <a class="edit" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" row_id="<?php $row->cat_id;?>">Edit</a>
                      <script type="text/javascript">
$('.edit').click(function() { 
 
  row_id = $(this).attr("row_id");
     alert(row_id);

 return false;
});
 
 
</script>     i have done this ..a value is not going into alert box ..a blank box is showing

Comment: Which model library are you using..?

Comment: well i dont think model is the issue ... ok if i dont use the model then tell me how can i add an id to it ..

Comment: because if you are using model library, and you want to open page in popup iframe, you must specify url in href tag.

Comment: this is colorbox library http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/, please check "Outside Webpage (Iframe)"

Comment: i used this in select box but there i used the select box id e.g <select id = "id">  but here i dont know how to do this

Comment: then u tell me what should i do now ??? how can i do this through popup ? i dont want to reload the page so user can able to edit the enteries

Comment: i want to send a request to the controller without a reload ? is there any other method then tell me

Comment: use colorbox library add $(".edit").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"}); <a class='edit' href="http://www.yourdomain.come/edit/<?php echo $row->cat_id;?>">Edit</a>

Comment: oohh dear i think u misunderstood .. look i have a table .. where lets say have ten rows .. in every row there is an edit button .. so what i want to do is . if i click on the edit button i can be able to edit the specific row ...how can i acheive this functionality ..

Comment: can you add this in your code .. so it will get more easy to me

Answer (score 0):

you can get id through setting custom property of anchor tag

`<a toggle="modal"  href="#myModal"id="edit" row_id="<?php echo $row->cat_id; ?>">Edit</a>`

and you can access this property using javascript, and append it your ajax url.

Comment: not working ... i just pop a alert box for testing and it says undefined

Comment: when i hover on the row_id ..its saying undefined property

Comment: $('#edit').click(function() { 
 
 var cat_id = $('#cat_id').val();
 alert(cat_id);

 return false;
});

Comment: please help me .. i am just stuck in here